# Showing that a function $f$ has a unique fixed point in a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, banach-fixed-point

> Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space, and suppose $f : X → X$ satisfies 
>   $$d(f(x), f(y)) < d(x, y)$$
>   for all $x \neq y \in X$. Show that f has a unique fixed point.

All I've gotten it so far is that we need to somehow use another function $g(x)=(x,f(x))$.

Thanks

Comment: Intuitively you could seach for the fixed point by reapplying $f$ over and over. if you do this you get a sequence of some sort. Can you say anything about convergence of this sequence?

Comment: Those downvoting should provide some kind of feedback.  The way I see it, this is a reasonable question with a reasonable amount of context given.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I agree. Moreover, it allows interesting answers.

Comment: Please also have a look at the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3139704/prob-7-b-sec-28-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-a-shrinking-self-map-of-a-co

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function 
$$
g(x) = d(x,f(x))
$$
Note that this is a continuous function (why?) over a compact space, so it attains its minimum.

Suppose for contradiction that the minimimum of $g$ over $X$ is **not** $0$.  That is, suppose that for every $x \in X$, $g(x) \geq \epsilon > 0$. By compactness, there is an $x^* \in X$ is such that $g(x^*) = \epsilon$.  Reach a contradiction (how?) to conclude that $g$ must have a minimum of $0$.

Uniqueness is easy using the inequality.

Comment: Thank you! Seems simple now that I see it, sometimes with maths you just get a complete mind blank.

Comment: Is this correct way to show $g$ is continuous?

$|g(x)-g(y)| = |d(x,f(x)) - d(y,f(y))| = |d(x,f(x)) - d(y,f(x)) + d(y,f(x)) - d(y,f(y)) | \leq d(x,y) + d(f(x), f(y)) \to 0 $ as $d(x,y) \to 0$

so in fact $g$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: @Abhay yes, that is a valid argument.

Comment: How did you get the last inequality in the uniformly continuous argument?

Comment: @Jaunemoto I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Show that $f$ is continuous.
2. Take $x_0 \in X$ and define $x_{n+1}:=f(x_n)$ for $n \ge 1$
3. By compactness of $X$ ,$(x_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence.
4. Show that the limit of this convergent subsequence is a fixed point of $f$
5. Show that this fixed point is unique.

Comment: Can it be shown that the whole sequence converges? If not, do you know a counter example?

Comment: @Hello it must, based on what's proven here.  *Each* subsequence converges to a fixed point, but each fixed point is unique, which means that each subsequence converges to the same element.

Comment: @Fred how would you show that the limit of the subsequence should be a fixed point? I can't see a quick way to do it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom well isn't it that each "convergent" subsequence converges to a fixed point? For your question to Fred, I think this follows from continuity.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $x=\lim x_{n+1} = \lim f(x_{n}) = f(\lim x_n)=f(x)$

Comment: @Hello you can use that to see that if the full sequence convereges, its limit is a fixed point.  However, that line of reasoning can't be directly applied to the subsequence.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Good point! and actually, if the map is only non-expansive, the set of accumulation points might not contain any fixed points. However, I think it can be shown that $f$ acts transitively on this set. (such examples are known in nonlinear perron-frobenius theory)